$A_1$ Du Val singularity and blow ups
Blowing up $\operatorname{Spec}K[x,y]=\mathbb{A}^2$ along $\operatorname{Spec}K[x,y]/(x^2,y)$ in the $U_B$ chart gives a singular point $U_B=\text{Spec}K[x,y][a]/(ya-x^2)$ at the origin. This singularity can be identified with the $A_1$ Du Val singularity in the following way.
Consider the group $G = \mathbb{Z}/2$ acting on $\mathbb{A}^2$ by $u,v \mapsto -u,-v$. The quadratic monomials $u^2, uv, v^2$ are $G$-invariant functions on $\mathbb{A}^2$, so that the map $\mathbb{A}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{A}^3$ given by $x = u^2$, $y = uv$, $z = v^2$ identifies the quotient space $\mathbb{A}^2/G$ with $X=\mathbb{V}(xy-z^2)$.
What is the point of this connection / identification ? Why is it important?
subquestion: The $A_1$  Du Val singularity is related to $x^2+y^2+z^2=0$ here not to $xy-z^2$ why is that?
Edit: I added a paper in the comments that might provide an answer.

The two equations you give for the $A_1$ singularity are isomorphic by change of coordinates.

@LazzaroCampeotti I noticed that, I thought it maybe had a deeper reason, I guess then we write $^2+^2+^2=0$ as coherent generalized formula.

Lemma 4.8. seems to be important / interesting https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s002220000101 Of course I lack the framework / skeleton (of what we are doing) to understand it, I've included it in hopes of aiding others who may possess the requisite framework.
